# PHP/iCal appointment reply target

Tags: php, icalendar, reply

I found several great tutorials for generating an event (`.ics`) email in PHP, such as [this one here.](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/04/14/generate-outlook-calendar-events-with-php-and-icalendar/)

However, I'm hoping that there is some way to possibly set up a "reply target" as a URL? I would like to avoid setting up a reply email catcher, which seems to be the way it works by default. Sorry, I'm fairly new to server operations. If I could get a POST or even just a unique URL to hit my server, I could store the response in my database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reliable way is with listening to email.

If the ITip client is hooked up to a CalDAV server (with caldav-scheduling support) it's possible to do it over HTTP, but you can't really count on this.

Comment: I'll accept this, I suppose. Since no one else is chiming in, I'll take that as it's the only way. Thanks!